# Emacs is unable to run code in swift-mode since upgrading to Catalina

Tags: swift, emacs, macos-catalina

When I try to run code in emacs swift-mode with C-c C-z, I receive the following message:

> 'warning: unable to find and load segment named '__OBJC_RO' at
>   0x7fff6e030000 in '/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib' in macosx dynamic loader
>   plug-in.
>
> warning: unable to find and load segment named '__OBJC_RW' at
>   0x7fff919d9080 in '/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib' in macosx dynamic loader
>   plug-in.'

I am running emacs version 26.3 and macOS version 10.15

Does anybody have a resolution for this issue?